# Error when trying to add new data to one of my tables

Tags: java, mysql, database, addition

Working on a project where I have to add new data to different tables (i'm new at this). I'm using Netbeans which is connected to a mysql database. The database is working fine and my queries work when I execute them directly. But when I try to update the tables with new data through my javacode, it fails.

**Code:**

```
ConnectionClass db = new ConnectionClass();
    try {
        db.ConnectToDb();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AddUser.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

      String sql = "insert into users values (3, 'Nicklas', 'niklas@alskart.se', 'nisun', 'heej', '1')";

       /* String laggTill = "insert into agent values ("+idb.getAutoIncrement("agent", "aid")+
            ", '"+tfNamn.getText()+"', '"+tfNr.getText()+"', '"+tfMail.getText()+"')";

      */

    try {
        db.myStmt.executeUpdate(sql);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AddUser.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
```

**Exception Generated:**

```
apr 10, 2015 1:17:47 EM Project.AddUser btn_saveNewUserActionPerformed
ALLVARLIG: null
    java.sql.SQLException: No operations allowed after statement closed.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:998)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:937)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:926)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:872)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.checkClosed(StatementImpl.java:445)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1554)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1549)
    at Project.AddUser.btn_saveNewUserActionPerformed(AddUser.java:159)
```

Comment: its clear from the error you have posted `ava.sql.SQLException: No operations allowed after statement closed. at `  that you are trying to access after closed

Comment: Show `ConnectionClass ` please.

Comment: I tried the query after I set up the connection but it's the same error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi see your stacktrace is says 
java.sql.SQLException: No operations allowed after statement closed.
means Statement object is not there.
your can do it in following way:

```
Statement myStmt;

try {
        myStmt = db.createStatement();
        myStmt.executeUpdate(sql);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AddUser.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

i assume that reference variable db is of type Connection.

Answer (score 0):

The basic steps when inserting data record to database are:

```
Connection connection //connect to db
PreparedStatement statement;
String query = "INSERT INTO...";
statement = connection.prepareStatement(query);  //prepareStement (or createStatement()) based on query
statement.executeUpdate();
```

I think you missed the prepareStatement() or createStatement() step.

So (I do not know what you ConnectionClass looks like, please publish it):

```
try {
        db.myStmt.createStatement();
        db.myStmt.executeUpdate(sql);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AddUser.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

**At the end you must close connection and statement.**

Working example: http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-statement-example-insert-a-record/